# How to resolve nginx internal server error

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, amazon-lightsail

I'm configuring Nginx as a public-facing proxy server to my internal Gunicorn server to host a "Reddit clone" Flask project I'm developing. At one point, Nginx was working properly (when I'd used mostly the same configuration as an online tutorial), but after making updates appropriate for my application, I'm getting an "Internal Server Error" when navigating to my Amazon Lightsail (Ubuntu 16.04) server's IP address, and reverting the changes back to the tutorial configuration now doesn't work.

I tried: 
1. Stopping and starting the Nginx service
2. Running `sudo netstat -tulpn`, finding the PID (seems to appear twice for the local addresses `0.0.0.0:80` and `0.0.0.0:443`), killing the process with `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp` and `sudo fuser -k 443/tcp` and then starting Nginx again
3. Completely removing Nginx from my system and reinstalling with:
`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nginx`
`sudo apt-get -y install nginx`

`flask_reddit` (my configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`):

```
server {
    # As Gunicorn documentation states, prevent host spoofing by blocking requests without "Host" request header set
#    access_log /var/log/nginx/flask_reddit/flask-reddit_access.log;
#    error_log /var/log/nginx/flask_reddit/flask-reddit_error.log;

    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
}

server {
#    access_log /var/log/nginx/flask_reddit/flask-reddit_access.log;
#    error_log /var/log/nginx/flask_reddit/flask-reddit_error.log;

    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
#    access_log /var/log/nginx/flask_reddit/flask-reddit_access.log;
#    error_log /var/log/nginx/flask_reddit/flask-reddit_error.log;

    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    client_max_body_size 5m; # Useful for situations such as file uploads; will return 413 code in violation of this limit
    keepalive_timeout 120s 120s; # Used to expedite request processing

    # location of the self-signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/flask-reddit/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/flask-reddit/certs/key.pem;

    location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off; # Preserve the fact that Gunicorn handled the request by disabling proxy_pass->location URL prefix change
        proxy_set_header Host $host; # When a domain name is configured, this will equal the name in lowercase with no port (protocol added in X-Forwarded-Proto)
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        root /home/ubuntu/flask-reddit/app;
        try_files $uri /templates/404.html; # Provide custom-written 404 response page
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (my main Nginx configuration file):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

When I run `sudo service nginx status`, I get the following output:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-08-29 04:07:42 UTC; 3 days ago
  Process: 21652 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4855 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 5.5M
      CPU: 1.521s
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─ 4855 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           └─21657 nginx: worker process                           

Sep 01 02:18:29 ip-172-26-5-151 systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 01 02:18:29 ip-172-26-5-151 systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 01 04:58:21 ip-172-26-5-151 systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 01 04:58:21 ip-172-26-5-151 systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

My `sudo netstat -tulpn` output is:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4855/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4036/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19927/master    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4855/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6398/python     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20037/python    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4036/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      19927/master    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           943/dhclient
```

Using `sudo nginx -t` says that this main Nginx configuration in `nginx.conf` is valid, but running `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit` gives:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit test failed
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: to check nginx config syntax issue `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` which will show the error in your config

Comment: After you try what Scott said, I'd pare your Nginx configuration down to just what's required to serve basic html, and log it, Then add things back in slowly. You should be using version control on your Nginx config. Looks like the logging is unavailable, rather than Nginx being unavailable, but until you get logging working you won't be able to tell much. Might be the app server has a problem and Nginx is just passing the error through.

Comment: @ScottStensland @Tim I followed your suggestions on testing config errors and updated my question with my findings. I did simplify by removing my log file paths since the `nginx.conf` main config does specify them, but left the rest of the reverse proxy parameters in place because I know for a fact that it did work in the past. I am stumped, however, on how to fix this current invalid custom config issue. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Lots of words here, clearly you've googled lots of solutions and copied and pasted them without understanding what they do (the error reported by `nginx -t` is nothing to do with the config but how you are using the command). The FIRST place to look when diagnosing any errors is in your log files - did you check if it was nginx or gunicorn returning the error?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your setup onto a box and tweaked it until now its working ... 
Use this as your location and you will be fine

```
location / {
    # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

}
```

Comment: I just tried this location block, and it doesn't seem to be working; I used it in place of my original "proxy" location block, reloaded using `sudo service nginx reload`, and then navigated to my site to find the same `Internal Server Error`. Using `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit` gives the same error: `nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit test failed`. Do you have any other tips?

Comment: easiest path to a working setup is to follow @Tim 's suggestion of purging nginx and do a fresh install then confirm its default config is OK then tiny bit add back functionality each time repeat the  `nginx -t` and `nginx -s reload` until you discover the actual cause ... its next to impossible to back seat drive these config questions although I did have my suggested solution working when I started from the fresh nginx install where the only change was to paste my above into the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-reddit` --- good luck

Comment: i would suggest using etckeeper as package on debian to save up any changes :D